# C++ identifiers

Tags: c++, identifier

C++ Primer says:

> The identifier we define in our programs may not contain 2 consecutive
>   underscores, nor can identifier begin with an underscore followed
>   immediately by an uppercase letter. In addition, identifiers be fined
>   outside of a function may not begin with an underscore

All is well, but

```
int _c = 55;                  // outside function starts with _

int main () {

    int _A = 12;              // _ followed by uppercase letter
    cout << _A << endl;

    int __b__ =33;            // 2 consecutive __
    cout << __b__ << endl;

    cout << _c << endl;

}
```

**Code above compiles perfectly fine** on mac, `g++ 4.7.1`, using the following flags

```
g++ -pedantic -Wall -Werror -std=c++11 -O3 -funroll-loops -fprefetch-loop-arrays
```

What am i missing please?

Comment: When you break the "rules", it's doesn't *guarantee* that it will not work. It just may or may not.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783/what-are-the-rules-about-using-an-underscore-in-a-c-identifier

Comment: NOt everything that isn't correct must fail to compile. Much like not every sentence that you can form in the English language must automatically make sense.

Comment: Also, you should avoid using identifiers that begins with an underscore and followed by *lowercase* letter (not only uppercase letters as mentioned in the book). In my compiler and OS, `_pthread_cleanup_buffer` is already used.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nothing. The identifiers with a leading underscore followed by an uppercase letter and identifiers with two underscores are merely reserved.

Your compiler vendor might decide to use them at any time (for instance, it's perfectly fine for a compiler vendor to use _A as a keyword) and hence you should not use them. Often, the standard library is implemented using reserved identifiers, hence they do not result in a compile error.

Comment: Is there a way to treat these as warnings?

Comment: Nope, that wouldn't work, as the compiler does not know what code is from the standard library and which one is yours.

Answer (score 9):

Crossing the street without looking out for traffic both ways doesn't *guarantee* that you are run over by a bus, but it is still a bad idea.

One of those days it isn't going to work...